# How do I remove all references to the Sample DB when using the Forena reports module on a server without PDO Sqllite?

Tags: forena

We have [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) installed on a server that doesn't have the PDO driver for Sqllite and would like to remove all references to the Sample DB repository so that Forena pages don't display an error about the missing driver. The users see a lot of:

> PDO driver support for sqlite not installed

I first tried removing permissions on the SampleDB repository as mentioned in one thread in the issue queue. This had no effect and the error message was still displayed.

I have tried using drupal_alter to remove the repos:

```
function mymodule_forena_repos_alter(&$repos) {
  if(isset($repos['forena_help'])){
    unset($repos['forena_help']);
  }
  if(isset($repos['sampledb'])){
   unset($repos['sampledb']);
 }
```

}

I then get a new error:

> Undefined repositorysampledb
>
> Undefined repositoryforena_help

I have tried patching the Forena module to unset the `settings.php` variables inside the sampledb folder. That also gives a new error along the lines of "PDO Driver not found".

How do I remove all references to the SampleDB repo? I would also like to remove the *Forena Help* and *Drupal Admin* repos if possible.

Comment: I don't use Forena, but it seems like the error's coming from plugins/FrxPDO.inc. You could just debug in there and figure out a change to make, if your only concern is the error. Pretty weird that it wants you to have it installed if you're not going to use it. You can't just install the driver?

Comment: Have you checked the configuration options? It seems like from this post, there might be an option to disable it.
https://www.drupal.org/project/forena/issues/1061436

Comment: Yes. I have edited my post to indicate that I tried the suggested fix and I don't want to install a new driver on this server at this point and go through configuration management changes.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from Dave's (Forena maintainer) [comment in a related Support Issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena/issues/1061436#comment-10608990):

> ... You might uncheck permissions associated with accessing sample reports to make sure other users don't see this error.

Using this approach you should be OK when upgrading to future versions.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena (and contributed quite a bit of the content of that `forena_help` repo you seem to be strugling with).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I already did this to no effect. I will edit my question.